# Strange error message printed out for KeyError

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x

Why is it that in Python 2.7

```
>>> test_string = "a \\test"
>>> raise ValueError("This is an example: %s" % repr(test_string))
ValueError: This is an example: 'this is a \\test'
```

but

```
>>> raise KeyError("This is an example: %s" % repr(test_string))
KeyError: This is an example: 'this is a \\\\test'
```

(notice the 4 backslashes)

Comment: The first example *also* produces 4 backslashes.

Comment: @MartijnPieters it doesnt for me, maybe a Python 3.x specific problem?

Comment: In fact `repr` will always produce four backslashes.

Comment: @RNar: This doesn't change between Python 2.7 and 3.5.

Comment: I can reproduce in Python 2.7.10.

Comment: @chepner: I can't. Python 2.7.10 on OS X. The string formatting with  `repr()` already produces those 4 backslashes.

Comment: @chepner: ah, the traceback module seems to be involved here.

Comment: odd, I can reproduce in 3.5...

Comment: Weird. Also OS X (10.10.5), in Python 3.4.3 as well.

Comment: It produces two backslashes for me for sure on Python 2.7.8 :: Anaconda 2.1.0 (64-bit)

Comment: What confused me was the `repr()` of exceptions shows the `repr()` of the `args` *tuple*. So `repr(KeyError(repr('\\')))` and `repr(ValueError(repr('\\')))` don't differ (both show the class name with `('\\',)`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `__str__` methods for `ValueError` and `KeyError` differ:

```
>>> str(ValueError(repr('\\')))
"'\\\\'"
>>> str(KeyError(repr('\\')))
'"\'\\\\\\\\\'"'
```

or using `print`:

```
>>> print str(ValueError(repr('\\')))
'\\'
>>> print str(KeyError(repr('\\')))
"'\\\\'"
```

That's because `KeyError` shows the `repr()` of the 'key' you passed in, so you can distinguish between a string and integer key:

```
>>> print str(KeyError(42))
42
>>> print str(KeyError('42'))
'42'
```

or more importantly, so you can still recognise an *empty string* key error:

```
>>> print str(KeyError(''))
''
```

The `ValueError` exception doesn't have to deal with Python values, it's message is meant to be a string, always.

From the [`KeyError_str()` function in the CPython source code](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Objects/exceptions.c#l1270):

```c
/* If args is a tuple of exactly one item, apply repr to args[0].
   This is done so that e.g. the exception raised by {}[''] prints
     KeyError: ''
   rather than the confusing
     KeyError
   alone.  The downside is that if KeyError is raised with an explanatory
   string, that string will be displayed in quotes.  Too bad.
   If args is anything else, use the default BaseException__str__().
*/
```

`ValueError` uses the [default `BaseException_str()` function](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Objects/exceptions.c#l99), which for the one-argument case just uses `str(arg[0])`.